# R: Shouldn't generic methods work internally within a package without it being attached?

Tags: r, generics, package, r-sp

I am writing a package that uses classes and functions from the spatial `sp` library. `sp` exports methods for `rbind` (am I correct in calling `rbind` a generic?).

For instance, the following code creates two *SpatialPoints* objects and then uses `rbind.SpatialPoints` to join them together:

```
> crdsA <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4), ncol = 2)
> crdsB <- matrix(c(7,8), ncol = 2)
> 
> sptsA <- sp::SpatialPoints(crdsA)
> sptsB <- sp::SpatialPoints(crdsB) 
> 
> sp::rbind.SpatialPoints(sptsA, sptsB)
SpatialPoints:
     coords.x1 coords.x2
[1,]         1         3
[2,]         2         4
[3,]         7         8
Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: NA
```

However, if I then convert the *SpatialPoints* to *SpatialPointsDataFrame* (a higher level object class within the `sp` library), and then use `rbind.SpatialPointsDataFrame`, I get an error:

```
> sptsdfA <- sp::SpatialPointsDataFrame(sptsA, data.frame(IDs = c(1,2)))
> sptsdfB <- sp::SpatialPointsDataFrame(sptsB, data.frame(IDs = 3))
> 
> sp::rbind.SpatialPointsDataFrame(sptsdfA, sptsdfB)
Error in rbind2(..1, r) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

A look at the `rbind.SpatialPointsDataFrame` [source code](https://github.com/edzer/sp/blob/master/R/rbind.R#L29) reveals that it calls `rbind` for *SpatialPoints*:

```
rbind.SpatialPointsDataFrame <- function(...) {
    dots = list(...)
    names(dots) <- NULL # bugfix Clement Calenge 100417
    sp = do.call(rbind, lapply(dots, function(x) as(x, "SpatialPoints")))
    df = do.call(rbind, lapply(dots, function(x) x@data))
    SpatialPointsDataFrame(sp, df, coords.nrs = dots[[1]]@coords.nrs)
}
```

So this seems to be the problem, but I do not understand why. If I attach the `sp` library, then none of these problems occur, but I thought that since `rbind` was being called internally within `rbind.SpatialPointsDataFrame`, then the rest of the library did not to be attached.

Within the context of the package I am creating, even if I include `import(sp)` and `importFrom(sp,rbind.SpatialPoints)` in the NAMESPACE, the code above does not work.

I guess there is clearly something I am not understanding with regards to loading, attaching and importing packages. Could anyone explain why `sp::rbind.SpatialPointsDataFrame` does not work without the rest of the library being attached, and how I can get it to work within my package?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`rbind` is not a usual generic: since its signature has `...` as its first (and only) argument, it cannot dispatch on the first argument. It has been problementic in all cases to program methods for it. Have you looked at `maptools::spRbind`?

Comment: Thanks. I have indeed used `maptools::spRbind` as a temporary (or maybe permanent?) solution. I read up on method dispatch [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html), and so that makes a bit of sense... although I don't quite understand how this relates to the package being attached or not?